# iphone - MKMapView callout doesn't show on iPhone 4 with iOS 4.1

Tags: iphone, dictionary, annotations, callouts

I have a problem with MKMapView. I add annotations like that:

```
// set up new points
for(int i = 0; i < [_locations count]; i++) {
    PPlace * place = [_locations objectAtIndex:i];
    PlaceAnnotation * placeAnnotation = [[PlaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlace:place];
    // if annotation is for currently selected place
    placeAnnotation.isCurrent = i == currentIndexPath.row;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:placeAnnotation];
    if (placeAnnotation.isCurrent) {
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:placeAnnotation animated:YES];
    }
    [placeAnnotation release];
}
```

So I try to display callout bouble immediately after added, not after annotation pin is tapped.
Everything works fine in simulator, also on iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.3.2. However, the callouts do not show on iPhone 4 with iOS 4.1 (they show only after pin is tapped). Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `PlaceAnnotation`? Maybe the title property returns an empty string.

Comment: You need to set `title` property on your annotation object.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you did not assign a value to the title property of your annotation class. Even though you may set `canShowCallout` to `YES`, the call out bubble will not show unless you have something in your title.

Comment: I do assign title and subtitle. If I wouldn't, the callout would never appear, doesn't matter if on simulator or device. But it does appear for example on simulator, or on iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
placeAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
```

so it looks like:

```
// set up new points
for(int i = 0; i < [_locations count]; i++) {
    PPlace * place = [_locations objectAtIndex:i];
    PlaceAnnotation * placeAnnotation = [[PlaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlace:place];
    // if annotation is for currently selected place
    placeAnnotation.isCurrent = i == currentIndexPath.row;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:placeAnnotation];
    if (placeAnnotation.isCurrent) {
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:placeAnnotation animated:YES];
        placeAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    [placeAnnotation release];
}
```

hope this helps!
WeSaM

Comment: It won't work, because placeAnnotation is not derived from MKAnnotationView. It's just a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: I have also class PlaceAnnotationView, which is a subclass of MKAnnotationView, created in - (MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation, and I do set there canShowCallout = YES. It doesn't work.

Comment: Set title on `MKPointAnnotation` object, used to represent pin data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the following method:

`- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation`

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it at the wrong time. You can't select it until after it has loaded.

Use the delegate method of the MKMapView:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
```

And from inside of that method call:

```
[yourMapView selectAnnotation: yourAnnotation animated: YES];
```